# C Array Wrong storage issue

Tags: c

in this code we want user to enter 5 numbers and store those five numbers inint array and then print out those 5 numbers in Array.but code below is only storaging users last input in array fives instead of storing remaining 4 other numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
  int Array[5];
  int i;
  int l=0;
  int k=0;
  int j=0;
  while(j<5)
  {
  printf("enter k value");
  scanf("%d",&k);
  j++;
  }

  // loop through and insert a  the  value
  // returned from the k .

  for ( i = 0; i < 5 ;i++){
  Array[i]= k; 
  }

  // loop through and print out the values at
  // each slot in the array

  for ( l = 0; l < 5;l ++ ) {
    printf ("Value %i: %d\n", Array[l]); // this only printing out the last input that user entered .
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you assign the the array elements in the *first* loop, where you have the different values? Now you use only the *last* read value. The problem would be bloody obvious if you just used a debugger and stepped through the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   i wouldnt have even asked the question if i was allowed to assign  array elements in first loop we cannot.

Comment: Then unless you can make `k` an array too, you're screwed. Either you have to assign to the `Array` elements in the first loop, or you need a second array.

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` loop, you read values into `k` each time, overwriting the value that was previously there.  Then you assign that single value to each element of the array, so of course all array element will contain the same value.

Instead of having one loop for reading and one for assigning, do them at once, passing in the address of the relevant array element.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5 ;i++){
    scanf("%d", &Array[i]); 
}
```

Note that you'll need to do error checking on the return value of `scanf` to make sure a value was read in and to flush the buffer using `getchar` in that case.

Comment: problem is we are not to allowed to do that

Comment: @RohitMereddy You should have mentioned that in your question.  If there are restrictions, we need to know what those are.  Can you instead read into `k` then assign to the array in the same loop?

Comment: @RohitMereddy So make `k` an array *too*?